# Wordpress best learning path

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Guys I am very good in **PHP, Sql, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, jQuery** and others plus I know how to work with **Laravel Frameword**.
I decided to start learning **Wordpress** because it is easy and fast in web development.

The question is what is the best path or tutorial should I start learning while I have all those web design and development background.

I found many tutorials on Youtube but I am very dispersed and don't know from where to start and what is the best tutorial I should start with.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea to start learning Wordpress, it's a fantastic CMS when used correctly. As you have most likely discovered there are lots of paths you can go down to learn how to develop themes, child themes and plugins and it really does depend on your preferred learning style.

**Free:**
If you like reading documentation, the Wordpress codex is fantastic and has everything and more that you will ever need to know. It explains the structure, what files do what and has code samples for each area:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
or search "Wordpress codex theme development".

Or if you like to follow videos and build a project and learn that way then this is an excellent playlist going from beginner to intermediate:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDRFZwNhlag&list=PLivfKP2ufIK6MfeczAaxnzqtyLX0z76Eu

**Paid:**
Teamtreehouse have a track for Wordpress theme development and also one for plugin development, this is an excellent way to learn as there's challenges, you follow along and there is an active discussion on most videos. (They currently offer a one month free trial, you could easily complete it in that time)

**What to learn:**
 - Theme file structure
 - Wordpress template hierarchy 
 - Install it locally
 - How the functions.php file works (To enqueue scripts, add actions and filters)
 - Custom post types and taxonomies (For news pages, products, events etc)
 - Advanced custom fields (To add additional fields such as text, image, file, repeater)

Once you've done that you will be well along the way, feel free to drop me a message if you need any help or have any questions, best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Like the above post says u will get only opinions so here gos lol

Personally i recommend underscores.me and then downloading a barebones version from there just play around and have fun, its a great way to learn imo as u have the freedom to do what u want. I would say with all ur exp u should use underscores and develop a website u have already made in past.

Failing that udemy has both free and paid tutorials